Is the probability measure P that's used always the same one?
I apologize if the question isn't too clear, I'm confused about how to word it since I'm new to this topic.
I've recently been trying to delve more into probability theory (with no background in measure theory or topology), and trying to understand some things.
So often in probability problems, I'll see something like $P[X\leq x]$ or $P[Y\leq x]$, with $P$ getting used everywhere. Does this mean that the probability measure used is the same, regardless of what random variable you're inputting? I imagine it's different if  $X$ is a continuous random variable and $Y$ is a discrete random variable, but what if, say, both are continuous?
Also, a reworded and possibly different question: if $X$ ~ $Normal$ and $Y$ ~ $t$-$distribution$, then by using the same probability measure $P: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, would $P[X\leq x]$ and $P[Y\leq x]$ give the right answer for the probability of each r.v.? And how does P do that if it does give the right answer?
If I'm not wrong, I'm guessing it's possible to use different probability measures, say $P_1: \Omega_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $P_2: \Omega_2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for random variables with different distributions, but the question is if you can use the same probability measure $P$ for both random variables and how does $P$ "know" that it's working with a normal distribution or a t-distribution, or any other distribution?

The usual notation leaves it implicit what the measure space is. A random variable is just a measurable function on the set of outcomes (or states) of the measure space: $X \le x$ and $Y \le x$ both determine events, i.e., measurable subsets of the set of outcomes. $P$ is a function on events: $P[X \le x]$ is a shorthand for $P({ \omega \mid X(\omega) \le x})$. $P$ doesn't need to "know" anything about the distribution of the random variables you might use to describe an event that you pass to it.

$P$ is just typically used universally to denote probability? It doesn't matter what type of distribution.

@RobArthan Ok, thank you! That actually helped clear it up.
